# C program that prints out another C program in Japanese

Tags: c, quine

There was a C program written for a contest that was formatted in ASCII art as a Japanese character.  When compiled and ran it printed out another program formatted in a different Japanese character, then another, then finally it printed out the first again.

I was looking for the code to that and could not find it on the internet.  I dont remember what contest nor what the name of the program was.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The International Obfuscated C Code Contest: http://www1.us.ioccc.org/main.html

I cannot find that specific program, but I will keep looking. When I find it I will edit my answer.

**Edit:**

I think you may be referring to the dhyang entry on this page: http://www1.us.ioccc.org/years-spoiler.html

**Edit:**
Above site is down. Here is again:

dhyang.c 2000 Don Yang
http://www.uguu.org/src_saitou_c.html

Comment: Yes thats it, i didnt remember it having a starting point, but that was the exact program i was looking for.